# Include EntityFrameWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, include

Estou trabalhando com o Entity Framework 6, fiz todas as configurações necessárias.
Tenho uma Classe Pessoa que possui uma Propriedade do Tipo Endereco, dentro de endereço tenho uma propriedade Municipio que por final tem uma propriedade do Tipo UF.
Tenho uma função que preciso recuperar todas as pessoas cadastradas e exibir numa grid, até ai tudo bem, porém os dados dos objetos que fazem parte da minha classe pessoa, não é carregado.
usei esse código:

```
 _dbcontext.Pessoas.Include(x => x.Endereco.Municipio.Uf).ToList();
```

Quando faço o Debug do projeto o EntityFramework gera o Sql corretamente, eu copio o sql e executo no sqlserver, os dados são exibidos da forma que eu esperava, porém as informações que o Entity traz do banco não são incluidas na propriedades da minha classe pessoa, apenas os dados existente na tabela pessoa e que são carregados.

Comment: Tem como você colocar os modelos na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 3):

Ou seja:

```
public class Pessoa 
{
    [Key]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public int EnderecoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Endereco Endereco {get; set;}
}

public class Endereco
{
    [Key]
    public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
    public int MunicipioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Municipio Municipio { get; set; }
}

public class Municipio
{
    [Key]
    public int MunicipioId { get; set; }
    public int UfId { get; set; }

    public virtual Uf Uf { get; set; }
}
```

Troque:

```
_dbcontext.Pessoas.Include(x => x.Endereco.Municipio.Uf).ToList();
```

Para:

```
_dbcontext.Pessoas.Include("Endereco.Municipio.Uf").ToList();
```

Ou ainda:

```
_dbcontext.Pessoas
    .Include(x => x.Endereco)
    .Include(x => x.Endereco.Select(e => e.Municipio))
    .Include(x => x.Endereco.Municipio.Select(m => m.Uf))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Tentei a primeira solução que sugeriu, continuou sem  funcionar. A segunda ele nem compila, mostra um erro em .Include(x => x.Endereco.Select(e => e.Municipio))

Answer (score 0):

tente esse

```
_dbcontext.Pessoas.Include("Endereco", "Endereco.Municipio", "Endereco.Municipio.Uf").ToList();
```